# How to get value of input field which is an array, by it's name using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code,I want to get values of p_id by using it's name. As i am new to javascript,please help me.

```
   <form>

        <input name="p_id[]" value="0"/>
        <input name="p_id[]" value="1"/>
        <input name="p_id[]" value="2"/>

    </form>
```

Comment: too broad. can you elaborate??

Comment: document.getElementsByName... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pure javascript method:

```
document.getElementsByName('p_id[]');
```

To get values of a particular one :

```
document.getElementsByName('p_id[]')[0].value;
```

Comment: Here is my code, I just want to get the values of selected checkboxes by using it's name which is an array.

    <form>

    <input type="checkbox" name="p_id[]" value="0"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_id[]" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="p_id[]" value="2"/>

</form>

Comment: please help with this also.!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try like this:

```
document.getElementsByName("p_id[]")[0].value;
```

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qhmohco5/

```
<form>

    <input name="p_id_1[]" value="0"/>
    <input name="p_id_2[]" value="1"/>
    <input name="p_id_3[]" value="2"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged JQuery:

```
$('input[name*="p_id"]').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('value'))
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfmdj4uk/)

This function finds all the input tags with the name containing the phrase `p_id` and logs their values.

The *= operator performs substring matching, so you can specify a pattern that you want to match.